# Load netcdf subset in Matlab

Tags: matlab, netcdf

G'day,

I have ocean model output in the form of netCDF files. The netCDF files are approximately 21GB, and the variables that I want to load are also pretty big (~ 120 * 31 * 300 * 400 sized matrices).

I want to load some of these variables from a netCDF file into MATLAB. Usually, I would do this via:

```
ncload('filename.nc',var1)
```

Which would load the variables `var1` into similarly named MATLAB variables. However, since I only need a single column of `var1`, I only want to load a subset of `var1` - This should speed up the loading process. For example, say,

```
size(var1)
>>   var1      120x31x260x381
```

I only want the 31st column, and loading the other 30 columns, and discarding the information seems like a waste of time. In other words, this is what I want to accomplish: `ncload('filename.nc',var1(:,31,:,:))`.

I know there are a few different netCDF toolboxes floating around, and I have heard that one can use a `stride` flag to only load every `xth` entry... but I'm not sure if it's possible to do what I want. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a current version of MATLAB, look for [NCREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ncread.html) and the example therein.

Comment: Brilliant. Here is what I used exactly:
`subsetdata = ncread('filename.nc','var1',[1 31 1 1],[Inf 1 Inf Inf],[1 1 1 1]);`